# How to extend droppable area of file inputs to area of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, file-upload, drag-and-drop

How can I accept files being dragged and dropped on a div as if they were dragged onto a target file input element?

This only works for `<input type="file" />`:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frm_upload">
    <input type="file" name="input_upload">
    <div id="div_upload">Drag & Drop here</div>
</form>

$(':file').change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData($('frm_upload')[0]);
    formData.append('input_upload', file);

    $.ajax({
       url: base_url,
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,                  
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       dataType: 'JSON',
       success: sucessBinder
    });
});
```

Is it possible without ajax to automatically bind dragged files to `<input type="file" />`?

Comment: You'll want to utilize on-drop, on-drag-enter, on-drag-exit attributes on html. The answer didn't quite satisfy my specific case. DM me for more info!

Answer (score 3):

You can put the div over the file input. To make it still accept dragged files, add `pointer-events: none` to the div.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" />
<div>Drop a file here</div>
```